# how to add plug in dependency in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to know why and how to add a plug in dependency for any project in eclipse.

Comment: I'd recommend you use apache maven as a tool which will take care of the dependencies ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[**Plug-in Dependencies from the Eclipse Documentation Archives**](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/editors/manifest_editor/dependencies.htm)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the project , choose properties, go to Java Build Path .. add jars or add external jars should solve your problem.

Comment: How about dependencies on other projects in the same workspace? It seems that those are not working.

Answer (score 1):

How to Resolve What Plugin to Add to the Dependencies

I needed to know what dependency to add (to an Eclipse Plug-in) as well as how to add it.  The errors I got in the Java code were:

```
The type org.eclipse.jface.text.source.Annotation cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

in the java 'package' statement and:

```
The hierarchy of the type JavaDecodePlugin is inconsistent
```

To find what plugin supplied the Annotation class I searched the 'plugins' directory of the where the Eclipse code was installed on my (windows) machine (\app\androidDev\eclipse) for a reference to that class:

```
C:\app\androidDev\eclipse\plugins>grep -r org.eclipse.jface.text.source.Annotation *
Binary file org.eclipse.jface.text_3.8.2.v20121126-164145.jar matches
Binary file org.eclipse.text_3.5.200.v20120523-1310.jar matches
```

it was referenced in two plugins/jars.  I searched the jars for the desired class.  The first plugin/jar didn't contain it, the second did.

```
C:\app\androidDev\eclipse\plugins>jar -tf org.eclipse.jface.text_3.8.2.v20121126-164145.jar |grep Annotations
org/eclipse/jface/text/link/LinkedPositionAnnotations.class
org/eclipse/jface/text/source/projection/ProjectionSupport$ProjectionAnnotationsPainter.class

C:\app\androidDev\eclipse\plugins>jar -tf org.eclipse.text_3.5.200.v20120523-1310.jar |grep Annotations
org/eclipse/jface/text/source/Annotation.class
org/eclipse/jface/text/source/AnnotationMap.class
org/eclipse/jface/text/source/AnnotationModel$1.class
org/eclipse/jface/text/source/AnnotationModel$2.class
org/eclipse/jface/text/source/AnnotationModel$AnnotationsInterator.class
org/eclipse/jface/text/source/AnnotationModel$InternalModelListener.class
org/eclipse/jface/text/source/AnnotationModel$MetaIterator.class
org/eclipse/jface/text/source/AnnotationModel$RegionIterator.class
org/eclipse/jface/text/source/AnnotationModel.class
org/eclipse/jface/text/source/AnnotationModelEvent.class
```

So I knew what plugin I needed now. As [Plug-in Dependencies](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/editors/manifest_editor/dependencies.htm) shows (as in the answer above) You need to go to 'Package Explorer' expand 'META-INF', open 'MANIFEST.MF', open the 'Dependencies' tab and click the 'Add' button on the 'Required Plug-ins' section, type part of the name of the plug-in in the 'Select a Plug-in text area, let it find the fullname of the plugin (perhaps select the desired plugin) and click Ok.

(This answer is somewhat to document the process so if I have to do this again after I forget what I did, I, and you, will know)